# How to retrive previous and next records using DateTime field?

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm developing a news page. I can list the sorted news items & print any news record. At the detail page I also need to display the links of previous and next pages, that's where I'm stuck.

Here are the fields:

```
Guid news.Id
DateTime news.CreateTime
DateTime news.StartDate
DateTime news.EndDate
Int news.Priority
```

**CreateTime** includes both date & time info ie; *CreateTime="2014-10-21T11:35:18.1732578+03:00"*
**StartDate** includes only date info ie; *StartDate="2014-10-21T00:00:00"*
So there might be so many records with same StartDate. In short; CreateTime is unique field, StartDate is not.

Below is the lambda expression that sorts & loads the records correctly:

```
var newsAll = Data.Get<News>()
  .OrderBy(n => n.Priority)
  .ThenByDescending(n => n.StartDate)
  .ThenByDescending(h => n.CreateTime)
  .ToList()
```

Here is how I retrive the news record:

```
 string strCurrentNewsTime = "20141019140523"; // from the URL

 var newsItem = Data.Get<News>()
     .Where(n => n.CreateTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") == strCurrentNewsTime)
     .First();
```

No problem yet! Now I need to find previous & next records. My failed code is:

```
// Previous record
var prevNews = Data.Get<News>()
    .Where(n => n.StartDate <= newsItem.StartDate && n.Id != newsItem.Id)
    .OrderByDescending(n => n.Priority)
    .ThenByDescending(n => n.StartDate)
    .ThenBy(h => h.CreateTime)
    .First();

string prevNewsTime = prevNews.CreateTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"); // to URL
```

How can I get the previous & next records correctly? My idea is:

- Sort & get the all items with given date
- Iterate the items until find the current record Id
- Grab previous and next records'
- Break the loop

Answer (score 1):

```
var prefItem = Data.Get<News>()
    .Where(n => n.CreateTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") < strCurrentNewsTime) //
    .OrderBy... // sort in the opposite order
    .First();

var nextItem = Data.Get<News>()
    .Where(n => n.CreateTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") >= strCurrentNewsTime) //
    .Drop(1)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

The second one can be combined with your original query

Comment: CreateTime is not the primary key field to sort the records, so there will be older or newer records.

Comment: Primary key can speed up a query but not change its result. Please elaborate.